# the difference between with and without 'else'

Tags: if-statement

I'm just start learning Python by myself, before that i have 0 experience in any language.
Here's a question I would like to ask you for help:

What's the difference between:

```
dict_food = {}
for food in ['ham','egg','bacon','egg','egg','egg','bacon','bread','bread']:
if not food in dict_food:
    dict_food[food] = 0
dict_food[food] += 1

for food, count in dict_food.items():
    print(count, food)
```

and this:

```
dict_food = {}
for food in ['ham','egg','bacon','egg','egg','egg','bacon','bread','bread']:
    if not food in dict_food:
        dict_food[food] = 0
    else:
        dict_food[food] += 1

for food, count in dict_food.items():
    print(count, food)
```

result for the first one is:

```
1 ham
4 egg
2 bacon
2 bread
```

and the second one is:

```
0 ham
3 egg
1 bacon
1 bread
```

How dose 'else' works in the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example:

```
dict_food[food] += 1
```

is performed in every iteration, as it is not part of the if-statement - but merely follows it.

In the second example, it is part of the if-statement and is therefore only performed conditionally:

```
if not food in dict_food:
    dict_food[food] = 0
else:
    dict_food[food] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

On **first situation**

both code lines will run

`dict_food[food] += 1` and `dict_food[food] = 0`

because it is not part of the if-statement - but merely follows it.

but on **second situation**

just only a line code run

`dict_food[food] = 0` or `dict_food[food] += 1`

because it is part of the if-statement